# Add WordPress custom taxonomy terms as css class

Tags: css, wordpress, taxonomy

On a custom post type archive I'm trying to add the custom taxonomy terms slug as a css class to the  tag. I've managed to get it to output the page->ID but struggling to get the $term->slug to work. Feel like I'm missing something really simple. Here's the full code, thanks for any help:

```
     <?php

$parent_pages = get_pages( array( 'parent' => 0, 'post_type'=> 'archive', 'orderby' => 'menu_order' , 'order' => 'ASC', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' ) );
foreach ( $parent_pages as $parent_page ) {


echo '<h1 class="page-heading" id="';
echo $parent_page->post_name;
echo '">';

echo $parent_page->post_title;
echo '</h1>';
 echo '<div class="wrapper grid4">';

$all_pages = get_pages(array( 'post_type'=> 'archive',  'orderby' => 'menu_order' , 'order' => 'ASC', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' ) );
$child_pages = get_page_children($parent_page->ID, $all_pages );
foreach ( $child_pages as $child_page ) {
  echo '<article class="post col ' . $child_page->ID, $term->slug .'">';

 echo '<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://www.iofpi.co.uk/civicworks.net/wp-content/plugins/pdfjs-viewer-shortcode/web/viewer.php?file=http://www.iofpi.co.uk/civicworks.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Citizen_Manchester.pdf" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" >';

  echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $child_page->ID, 'medium');

  echo '</a>';


    echo '<h1>';
  echo $child_page->post_title;
  echo '</h1>';
  echo '</article>';
}
     echo '</div>';
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: from where are you getting value of  "$term->slug" ?

Comment: Not sure I understand, I've added some custom taxonomy and thought I could just use $term->slug to output the taxonomy. How would I get them?

Comment: before foreach use below code see whole object.

echo "<pre>";
print_r($child_pages);
echo "</pre>";
die();

Comment: Refer this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function `get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy )` just pass it the post id in your case '$parent_page->ID' and the Name of taxonomy to retrieve terms from. For example: 'category', 'post_tag', 'taxonomy slug'

It will return an object and you can then access the slug with, say `$result->slug`.

Comment: Thanks, so would it look something like this: `$term = get_the_terms( $parent_page->ID, $media );` and where would I place this? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Yes , but what is this `$media` , you have to place your taxonomy name here. Place it after `$child_pages = get_page_children($parent_page->ID, $all_pages )` and access the slug now with $term->slug .

Comment: Feel like I'm almost there and missing something stupid, but still it just returns the ID and not the term `foreach ( $child_pages as $child_page ) {
 $terms = get_the_terms( $parent_page->ID, 'media' );
echo '<article class="post col ' . $child_page->ID, $terms->slug .'">';`

Comment: var dump this  `$terms` and see the result , does it have an empty value for the slug field. ?

Comment: returns bool(false) Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

If I pass it the $child_page->ID it returns the term, but `  echo '<article class="post col ' . $child_page->ID, $term->slug .'">';` won't display it. Am I doing something wrong with $term->slug? Thanks

Comment: The custom post type you are working with has a compatibility of post or a page. ?

Comment: Custom post type compatibility is post. I've got a feeling it should be something like . $child_page->term->slug . but not sure that's correct way to do it.

Comment: If it's post then why are you using `get page children`. ? This function is for retrieving pages.

Comment: Even if I switch to compatibility page it still doesn't work. Should it make a difference?

Comment: I'm not asking for you to switch anything. Give me simple answer why are using `get_the_children` function (as it used to retrieve sub pages of parent page, which is not your case)?

Comment: If you look at the code above, you'll see I'm outputting a series of parent pages and child pages. I just need to return the terms on the  $child_page bit of the loop.

Comment: Pages never have taxonomies , only posts have. This is why I asked you about the compatibility